# Why is the sound not playing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mpmediaitemcollection

So this is the code I have:

At the press of a button:

```
-(void)mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
self.selectedSong = mediaItemCollection;
    NSLog(@"Selected song: %@", self.selectedSong);
}
```

Later on:

```
-(void)waitUntilSpeechIsDone {
    NSLog(@"Test");
    if ([audio isEqualToString:@"Music"]) {
    if ([musicWhenToStart isEqualToString:@"Before"]) {
        NSLog(@"Test");

        NSLog(@"Selected song: %@", self.selectedSong);
        [self.musicPlayer stop];
        [self.musicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection:self.selectedSong];
        [self.musicPlayer play];
    }
    }   
}
```

It's defined as:

```
@interface RewriteViewController : UIViewController <MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate> {

    MPMediaItemCollection *selectedSong;

}
@property(nonatomic,retain) MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer;
@property(nonatomic,retain) MPMediaItemCollection *selectedSong;


MPMediaItemCollection *selectedSong;
```

Then both are synthesized in the .m file.

Ok, so it gets through the first half fine. The NSLog returns something like "Selected song: " Then NSLog returns "Test", (i put that there so i know it's got that far in case it crashes at the next line for some reason). Then when it gets to the next line it returns "Selected song: (null)".

Any ideas why?

EDIT: Both are released in dealloc.

Comment: Include the stack trace of the crash if you can, please.

Comment: There isn't a crash. It just returns as null and so the audio doesn't play.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your interface file, it appears you are declaring `MPMediaItemCollection *selectedSong;` twice :/ I'm not sure if this was a typo in posting the question, but that might have something to do with it. You crash is most likely related to `selectedSong` being released at some point when you don't expect it, and an bad declaration could be causing that.

Comment: I commented out the last one. It still returns as null.

Comment: And you aren't releasing `selectedSong` or mucking with it anywhere else in your application? This is all within the same class, correct? `RewriteViewController`

Comment: The app also has the option of doing the following code, but it's always 1 or the other. Don't have problems doing it this way. And it's all in RewriteViewController, yes.  `if ([musicWhenToStart isEqualToString:@"Start"]) {
  [musicPlayer stop];
   NSLog(@"selected song: %@", selectedSong);
  [musicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection:self.selectedSong];
  [musicPlayer play];
  }`

Comment: hmm, I'd try running your app against the debugger and tracking the value of `selectedSong` through the entire application life-cycle. Make sure it isn't being invalidated/released somewhere.